# How to use $route in Vue 2 Vuex store?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex, router, store

I have an Nuxt application which contains dynamic stores. This store has a method which looks like this:

```
loadCampaign({ commit, dispatch, state }) {
try {

    const share_token = this.$route.query.share_token;

    let campaign = null;

    share_token
                ? campaign = await this.$api.campaigns.getSharedCampaign(share_token)
                : campaign = await this.$api.campaigns.getCampaign(state.id);
    ...
```

This code thorws an error about $router is undefined. How can I get the router inside the Vuex store (dynamic store)? Why it does not work like this.$api which is another plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you console.log ```this``` ? Do you see ```$router``` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your `shareToken` value as a param from your vuejs component when dispatching the store action.

EDIT: added example

```
// inside vuejs component

this.$store.dispatch('loadCampaign', this.$route.query.share_token)


// vuex

loadCampaign({ commit, dispatch, state }, shareToken) {
    // ... your code
}
```

Comment: Yes it could be the way. But I would like to have it in the one place. I think I have a solution. `this.$router.currentRoute.query.share_token` Thanks.

Comment: @Čamo you can import router inside your vuex store `import router from '.../router.js' // Vue router instance` and then use router variable. I'd still suggest keeping your store actions clean and without too much logic.

Comment: @Čamo you could totally pass a default param to your vuex action.